# Badly rendered controls in NSToolbar

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I've tried to add buttons and segmented control into the toolbar, but they are badly rendered ([Image for the better imagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25pzJ.png)) - too thin, no matter what I do, I set even max and min size of NSToolbarItem, nothing works. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to solve this is manually finding the correct size, due to mac rendering machine is computing the correct size (font and text) + padding.